# SQL to ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having problems writing an ActiveRecord query.

I've what I need on SQL

```
SELECT "flags".* FROM "flags" INNER JOIN "flag_histories"
 ON "flag_histories"."flag_id" = "flags"."id" WHERE "flags"."external_organization_id" = 2 AND
  ((start_active <="2018-10-16"  AND  end_active >=  "2018-10-16")
  OR ( start_active <= "2018-10-16" AND end_active IS NULL)) GROUP BY "flags"."id")
```

And this is what I tested on rails with no success

```
  Flag.joins(:flag_histories)
  .where("end_active >= :date AND start_active <= :date",
            {date: date})
  .or("end_active is null AND start_active <= :date",
            {date: date})
  .where(flags: {external_organization_id: org_id})
  .group(:id)
```

By now I'm getting

wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
Extracted source (around line #28):

```
  .or("end_active is null AND start_active <= :date",
```

Can someone give me a hand with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you write your condition using a single `where` call, such as:

```
Flag.joins(:flag_histories)
    .where(
       "external_organization_id = :org_id AND
        (start_active <= :date AND end_active >= :date
         OR start_active <= :date AND end_active IS NULL)",
       { date: date, org_id: org_id }
    ).group('flags.id')
```

or:

```
Flag.joins(:flag_histories)
    .where(external_organization_id: org_id)
    .where(
       "start_active <= :date AND end_active >= :date
         OR start_active <= :date AND end_active IS NULL",
       { date: date }
    ).group('flags.id')
```

(I assume that each of `external_organization_id`, `start_active` and `end_active` fields are present in either `flags` or `flag_histories` tables, not in both, otherwise in the condition they need to be prepended with the correct table name)

**UPDATE**:

I have never used the method `or` before, but as [the documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) says it has some specifics and cannot be used in the same way as `where`. Instead of condition, it should have another `Relation` as an argument:

> ```
> # File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb, line 622
> def or(other)
>   unless other.is_a? Relation
>     raise ArgumentError, "You have passed #{other.class.name} object to #or. Pass an ActiveRecord::Relation object instead."
>   end
>
>   spawn.or!(other)
> end
> ```

Comment: external_organization_id is only on flags, and start_active and end_active is only on flag_histories.

Comment: So the query from answer should work without modification. I updated my answer -- see remark about "OR"

Comment: Tried with this and worked! Thanks a lot

`
Flag.joins(:flag_histories)
      .where(
         "flags.external_organization_id = :org_id AND
          (flag_histories.start_active <= :date AND flag_histories.end_active >= :date
           OR flag_histories.start_active <= :date AND flag_histories.end_active IS NULL)",
         { date: date, org_id: org_id }
      ).group(:id)
`